# Get A Specific Element Of A Website And Display It To Cover The Whole Screen?

Tags: html, web, iframe

I need to get the game window of [bonk.io](https://bonk.io) and get it to display on my entire screen, while still having the window function and be able to connect to the servers.

tysm :)

Comment: adding `position: absolute; top:0; left: 0; width: 100vw; height: 100vh;` to the game window element should work

Comment: I just tried it and because it's a iframe this is going to be more difficult

Comment: I got it to kinda work by adding the above CSS to the iframe element, the canvas element, and removing position: relative on <div id="bonkiocontainer"

Comment: How Do I Integrate This?
document.querySelector("#descriptioncontainer").remove(); 
document.querySelector("#adboxverticalCurse").remove(); 
document.querySelector("#adboxverticalleftCurse").remove(); 
document.querySelector("#bonkioheader").remove(); 
document.querySelector("#maingameframe").style.margin = "0px";
document.querySelector("#maingameframe").contentWindow.document.querySelector("#pagecontainer").style.width = "100%"; 
document.querySelector("#maingameframe").contentWindow.document.querySelector("#pagecontainer").style.height = "100%";

Comment: [ask]..........